# C++ Why does the "const volatile" type qualifier exist?

Tags: c++, constants, volatile

Say I have some object declared as `const volatile`:

According to the C++ standard ($7.1.5.1/8):

> [..] volatile is a hint to the implementation to avoid aggressive
>   optimization involving the object **because the value of the object
>   might be changed** by means undetectable by an implementation.[...]

However, the `const` qualifier implies than the object is ***not*** subject to change, so the two qualifiers appear to conflict:

One implies the object should be treated differently because it is subject to change, and the other implies it should be treated differently because it is *not* subject to change.

So, why are variables allowed be be `const volatile` in the first place?

Comment: It might make sense when accessing memory mapped read-only hardware registers.

Comment: `const` means *you* may not change the variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define

```
const some_type x = some_value;
```

that means you can't modify the value of `x`.  In the absence of `volatile`, the compiler can replace a reference to `x` by `some_value`.

If you define

```
const volatile some_type x = some_value;
```

then you still can't modify `x` (at least not by using the name `x`), but the compiler can no longer assume that its value cannot change.  Any reference to the value of `x` must actually load its value from memory; it can't assume that it will always retain its initial value.

For example, there might be some compiler-specific attribute that associates `x` with some device.  The name `x` provides a read-only view of the object; the `volatile` inhibits certain optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn’t make much sense:

```
int const volatile x = 42;
```

You’re right, `x` cannot be changed — drop `volatile`. However, the following is different:

```
int x = 42;
int const volatile& y = x;
```

Now `y` cannot be changed, but `x` can, and its change propagates through to `y`. This works regardless of `volatile`, of course — but if the change to `y` comes from a source that is unobservable to the C++ compiler, `volatile` may become necessary. Of course in cases where `volatile` makes sense, the pointer/reference wouldn’t just refer to any other variable but rather to a specific memory address that is mapped to the hardware or elsewhere.

Comment: A great and definitive answer, it explains the very gist volatile constants spread the underlying value it relies on.